# Importing libGDX project in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, libgdx

I'm trying to import my libGDX project build by the official Libgdx project generator.
Then I get this message:
     Gradle 'Project' project refresh failed
          Error:C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\gradle-versions\gradle-1.12-all\gradle-1.12\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all\2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo\gradle-1.12-all.zip.lck (System can't find the specified path)
What am I doing wrong?
FW

Comment: Try changing the gradle version in the .gradle file. Look at your other gradle projects (android projects that work) and change the gradle build version to what you've used before. This may not work but when i imported a libGDX project it tried using the wrong version. I also updated gradle to the latest which may of helped the issue.

Comment: I tried to change the gradle version but nothing worked. With each gradle version I'm getting this error message.

Comment: It seems that gradle has some kind of lock system? Which is why the file ends with a zip.lck? Have you navigated or tried navigating to the path that it is trying to open? You should try settingup the PATH variables for gradle. http://blog.blundell-apps.com/setting-up-android-studio-gradle-windows-7/